# Is it possible to query_posts using post__in and then Loop through them in the ordered they were queried?

Tags: query-posts, loop

```
query_posts( array ( 'post__in' => array( 5, 76, 21, 56, 3 ) ) );
```

I'd like to query the Loop using `post__in` and a set Wordpress IDs. I'd then like to run through the Loop in the exact order of the query. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sort-query-by-post-in/

Also see http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13729

Comment: I spent all my time searching the Wordpress Codex that I didn't think to look in the plugins... Thanks!

Comment: Hoping they implement this in 3.5. Thanks!